# Force a loop to start with a specific element? (Perl)

Tags: perl

I am opening a link with `LWP` and in the response there are other links i want to open too in order to `//DoSomething` on each of them, and among them there is link i just opened, i guess it is a bit confusing, well here is the code i am using :

```
my $request = GET $topic;
my $response = $ua->request($request);
usleep(52000);

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
$tree->parse($response->decoded_content);

my $link_1 = $tree->look_down('id' => 'link_1')->look_down('_tag' => 'a')->attr('href');
my $link_2 = $tree->look_down('id' => 'link_2')->look_down('_tag' => 'a')->attr('href');
my $link_3 = $tree->look_down('id' => 'link_3')->look_down('_tag' => 'a')->attr('href');

//then i insert them in an array

push @links, $link_1;
push @links, $link_2;
push @links, $link_3;
```

now let say for example that `$link_2` and `$topic` are the same

```
foreach my $link (@links)
{   
    if($link ne $topic)
    {
        $request = GET $link;
        $response = $ua->request($request);
        usleep(52000);

        $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
        $tree->parse($response->decoded_content);
    }


    $json = $tree->look_down('id' => 'json_text')->attr('_content')->[0];
}
```

What i want now is to not open the link twice, cuz perl doesn't loop through the array respecting the order of the push, cuz i tried to `push @links, topic;` right in the beginning and then make sure `@links` doesnt have a link like `$topic` before each `push @links, $link_?` but it doesnt work, in other words, i want to skip opening a link twice or print in the right order of push.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick I use for this kind of problem is to use a hash instead of an array.  An array is an excellent element when you want an order list of elements, whereas a hash is an excellent element when you want an UN-ordered list that is indexed.  So, for you problem, I would use a solution like thus:

```
my %links
# then i insert them in a hash

$links{$link_1} = 1;
$links{$link_2} = 1;
$links{$link_3} = 1;
```

Then, to check for the existence of the link:

```
foreach my $link (keys(%links))
{   
    if($link ne $topic)
    {
        # and so on and so forth
```

I believe this answers your question.  If I didn't understand your question and lead you down a wrong path, let me know.

*Update from the comments:*

If you you don't want to go through all of your stored links, simply check the hash to see if it contains topic.  If it doesn't, then you can go about with the download:

```
if (!defined($links{$topic})) {
    # and so on and so forth
```

Comment: Thank you :D, I am thinking on using a a hash instead, however i want to force my loop to start with `$topic` first then continue with the rest, I dont know if it is possible

Comment: @Mugiwara Take a look at the updated answer that shows how to only download the topic if it doesn't exist.